# NanoHTTP авторизация

Tags: java, веб-программирование, nanohttpd

С помощью чего реализовать процедуру авторизации в NanoHTTP? То есть пользователь на странице авторизации вводит логин пароль после чего именно этот пользователь (из этого браузера) получает доступ к остальному набору html страниц.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по тому, что я вижу в репозитории NanoHTTP не предоставляет готовых средств для авторизации пользователя (да и вообще мало что предоставялет, на то он и **Nano**HTTP). Так что придутся реализовывать ручками. Общий алгоритм примерно такой:

- После сабмита формы авторизации проверять логин и пароль.
- Если все ок, генерируем уникальный ключ для пользовательской сессии, кладем в какой-нибудь `Map` по ключу информацию о пользователе: когда залогинился, какие права имеет, таймстамп последней активности.
- Отдаем этот ключ пользователю в куку.
- При каждом запросе проверяем куку:

  - Если куки нет - отправляем логиниться.
  - Если кука есть, но сесссия просрочена (смотрим таймстамп) - отправляем логиниться.
  - Если кука есть, сессия не просрочена, но нет прав - говорим, что нет прав.
  - Если все хорошо - отдаем страницу.
  - Если сессия жива - обновляем таймстамп.

Это очень базовая схема. Вероятно вы захотите улучшить алгоритм, чтобы нельзя было воспользоваться чужой кукой. И чистить протухшие сессии по расписанию.